# Django Template For Loop Iterator Not Usable

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django template the following syntax works just fine:

```
{% for test in testing.1 %}
```

but when replacing the fixed 1 with a dynamic variable from an outer for loop it doesn't work at all:

```
{% for i in range %}
    {% for test in testing.i %}
```

When printing {{ i }} it shows 1, 2 and 3 like it should. Do I have to convert the i-variable somehow? Or can't I use the iterator variable there?

Comment: Django template does not support dictionary lookup with variable as key. You need to prepare the data from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @svrw commented: a dictionary lookup can't use a variable as key. I had to prepare the data so that I could use

```
{% for element in range %}
    {% for test in element %}
```

and get the correct output. My data in the views.py I changed from this:

```
range = {
    1: data1,
    2: data2,
    3: data3
}
```

to:

```
data1 = [element1, element2, element3 ...]
...
range = [data1, data2, data3]
```